# jquery change current row class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with rows in it.

I want to highlight the different rows as I use the down or enter key.  I have the keypress event working but I'm having issue with changing the current row to the original non-highlighted class.

I have figured out how to change the value of the next row, but I would need to reset the value from the row I'm coming from.

This is the code that I'm using to change the next "TR" to the highlighted class:

```
$(a).closest("tr").next().toggleClass("LUGridRowHighlight");
```

Please let me know.

**Update:**

I have a table with 5 rows of data.
My keypress code will eventually move up or down the table with the 5 rows

"a" represents the tablerow element

When I press the down arrow (keycode 40) I want to change the currently selected row that has class LUGridRowHighlight to just LUGridRow.  Then I want to change the row below to the highlight class.

Right now all I can do is change the row below to the highlighted class.  I want to also change the class of the row I'm coming from.

Comment: can you provide some more code? WHere this code fires? Whats the html?

Comment: `a` represents? Keypress code? reset what exactly? please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set all of the "non-highlighted" rows to the "non-highlighted" class:

```
$('#table_id tr').removeClass("LUGridRowHighlight");
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `toggleClass` returns a jquery object, so you should be able to do:

```
$(a)
  .closest("tr")
  .toggleClass("LUGridRowHighlight")
  .next()
  .toggleClass("LUGridRowHighlight");
```

or:

```
$(a)
  .closest("tr")
  .removeClass("LUGridRowHighlight")
  .next()
  .toggleClass("LUGridRowHighlight");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(a).closest("tr").nextAll("tr").find("tr:first").toggleClass("LUGridRowHighlight");
```